# Sorting through API response

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

I'm trying to loop through an API response to only show unique, non-repeating ip-srcs: and its value. I managed to figure out how to do the call in Python, and show the output in json format but I'm having trouble filtering the dictionary, to only show ip:src and its value. Ive tried different methods but no luck. Any suggestions

Heres my initial code:

```
data = '{ "query": "+basetypes:(indicator_attribute) +type:\\"ip-src\\" +timestamp:[now-300d TO now]", "_source_includes": [ "type", "value" ] }'
    
response = requests.post('https://notarealapi.com/api/v4/all/search', headers=headers, 
data=data)
data2 = response.json()

data3 = data2['hits']['hits']
result = {}

for index,item  in enumerate(data3):
  temp = {}
  temp['ip-src'] = item['_source']['value']['ip-src']
  result[index]=temp
print("List of unique ip-srcs:\n")
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Heres what my api response is currently:

```
 {0: {'ip-src': '193.56.28.103'},
 1: {'ip-src': '62.173.147.175'},
 2: {'ip-src': '194.90.6.2'},
 3: {'ip-src': '103.94.157.5'},
 4: {'ip-src': '62.77.33.18'},
 5: {'ip-src': '23.83.209.13'},
 6: {'ip-src': '89.163.241.193'},
 7: {'ip-src': '62.77.33.18'},
 8: {'ip-src': '80.74.144.29'},
 9: {'ip-src': '240.140.48.116'},
 10: {'ip-src': '159.65.140.182'},
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: an output that does have any repeating ip-srcs like 62.77.33.18 so:  {0: {'ip-src': '193.56.28.103'},
 1: {'ip-src': '62.173.147.175'},
 2: {'ip-src': '194.90.6.2'},
 3: {'ip-src': '103.94.157.5'},
 4: {'ip-src': '62.77.33.18'},
 5: {'ip-src': '23.83.209.13'},
 6: {'ip-src': '89.163.241.193'},
 7: {'ip-src': '80.74.144.29'},
 8: {'ip-src': '240.140.48.116'},
 9: {'ip-src': '159.65.140.182'},

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the following output:

```
{
 0: '193.56.28.103',
 1: '62.173.147.175'
}
```

In that case, you should store the result (which is `item['_source']['value']['ip-src']`) in a simple variable, instead of storing it in another `dict`.

To make it work, your loop should look like this:

```
for index,item  in enumerate(data3):
  temp = item['_source']['value']['ip-src']
  result[index]=temp
```

Or even simpler, you could do:

```
for index,item  in enumerate(data3):
  result[index] = item['_source']['value']['ip-src']
```

Comment: Hey! So I wanted the output to just show unique ip-src values, meaning any value that repeats more than once, should not be included in the output. For example ip-src: 62.77.33.18' appears twice in line 4 and 7. I only want it to appear once in the output along with any other value thats unique. I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by counting the number of occurrences of each ip-src and only printing out those that occur only once. An easy way to do that would be to use the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dictionary subclass to count how many of each occurs, and then only print out those with a count of 1.

```
from collections import Counter

data3 =  {0: {'ip-src': '193.56.28.103'},
          1: {'ip-src': '62.173.147.175'},
          2: {'ip-src': '194.90.6.2'},
          3: {'ip-src': '103.94.157.5'},
          4: {'ip-src': '62.77.33.18'},
          5: {'ip-src': '23.83.209.13'},
          6: {'ip-src': '89.163.241.193'},
          7: {'ip-src': '62.77.33.18'},
          8: {'ip-src': '80.74.144.29'},
          9: {'ip-src': '240.140.48.116'},
          10: {'ip-src': '159.65.140.182'},}

counts = Counter(value['ip-src'] for value in data3.values())

print("List of unique ip-srcs:\n")
for ip_src, count in counts.items():
    if count == 1:  # Unique?
        print(ip_src)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the dictionary using the values of the inner dictionary to eliminate duplicates the create a final dictionary from the filtered values:

```
data1 = {0: {'ip-src': '193.56.28.103'}, 1: {'ip-src': '62.173.147.175'}, 2: {'ip-src': '194.90.6.2'}, 3: {'ip-src': '103.94.157.5'}, 4: {'ip-src': '62.77.33.18'}, 5: {'ip-src': '23.83.209.13'}, 6: {'ip-src': '89.163.241.193'}, 7: {'ip-src': '62.77.33.18'}, 8: {'ip-src': '80.74.144.29'}, 9: {'ip-src': '240.140.48.116'}, 10: {'ip-src': '159.65.140.182'}}

data2 = [] # list to hold unique values
for k,v in data1.items():
    if v not in data2: #append items that do not already exist in data2 
        data2.append(v)  
final_dict = dict([(data2.index(a),a) for a in data2]) #create a final dictionary
print(final_dict)
```

> Output

```
{0: {'ip-src': '193.56.28.103'},
1: {'ip-src': '62.173.147.175'},
2: {'ip-src': '194.90.6.2'},
3: {'ip-src': '103.94.157.5'},
4: {'ip-src': '62.77.33.18'},
5: {'ip-src': '23.83.209.13'},
6: {'ip-src': '89.163.241.193'},
7: {'ip-src': '80.74.144.29'},
8: {'ip-src': '240.140.48.116'},
9: {'ip-src': '159.65.140.182'}}
```